# How to stop an event when i click on another, when both events going to same activity

Tags: android

I have two events both are going to same activity, if i click on one event and again click on another event it shows the same action.How to resolve this

Comment: Please elaborate your question in detail.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Answer (score 0):

In you are using views in order to trigger those events, then after clicking on the first view which triggers the event, you can disable the second view.

Answer (score 0):

You didnt upload your code so I am guessing that in the implementation of of your listeners class you are referencing the same view and ofcourse it gives the same result no matter how many events you fire.